# How does % positioning and sizing work in HTML?

Tags: html, css

The below image is 3 DIV's with `position:absolute` rendered in Chrome. All belong to the same parent DIV.

- Green and Red have `left:25%` and Purple has `left:50%`.
- Red has `left:25%` and `width:25%`.

**Question:** why does Red extend into Purple, instead of just touching Purple's left side?

[image: DIVs]

Comment: if possible provide fiddle

Comment: Does the red div have padding applied to it?

Comment: Have you set an border or padding to your elements? These add to the size of your elements making them larger than the width you have assigned. Show some more code please!

Comment: It works properly here: http://jsfiddle.net/dfc3G/ maybe you're problem is located elsewhere, post your html and css maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have set some `padding` to that div.

Please set `padding:0px;` then try again.